# Salesforce input connector in Alteryx

Tags: salesforce, alteryx

I am trying to bring in Salesforce data into my workflow. I have used the Salesforce Input tool and logged in my Credentials successfully. Then I select a table from the drop down in the "Query Type" menu and the "Query Builder" option, choose some fields in the "Optional Parameters" and run the workflow, but it gives me the following error.

> INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not providing a security token because your IP address is white-listed, then your error is probably due to an Alteryx bug that prevents the workflow from running successfully when no security token is provided. This bug will be fixed in the next Alteryx release. There is also a patch available from support@alteryx.com. Alternatively, you could de-white-list your IP address, obtain a security token from Salesforce, and try again in Alteryx.